# Bluetooth headset keeps connecting and disconnecting

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluez

My Soundcore Life Q30 connects, then disconnects, then reconnects, then reconnects... It keeps endlessly doing this. I've tried removing the device, removing /var/lib/bluetooth and /var/lib/blueman, restarting, reinstalling bluez-tools, and restarting the bluetooth service, blocking bluetooth with rfkill, but nothing has worked so far and the device keeps reconnecting and disconnecting.

When I run `bluetoothctl scan on` I get the following output on repeat:

```
$ bluetoothctl scan on
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 UUIDs: 66666666-6666-6666-6666-666666666666
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: yes
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Paired: no
[CHG] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Connected: no
[DEL] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
[NEW] Device AC:12:2F:EF:A6:D1 Soundcore Life Q30
```

Running `tail -F /var/log/syslog` gives me the following, also on repeat:

```
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: blueman-applet 09.59.13 ERROR    PluginManager:210 run       : Function on_device_property_changed on SerialManager failed
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 97, in get
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     prop = self.call_sync(
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:  (41)
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 207, in run
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     ret = getattr(inst, func)(*args, **kwargs)
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 52, in on_device_property_changed
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     self.terminate_all_scripts(device["Address"])
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 139, in __getitem__
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     return self.get(key)
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 110, in get
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     raise parse_dbus_error(e)
Oct 25 09:59:13 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: blueman.bluez.errors.BluezDBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: blueman-applet 09.59.19 ERROR    PluginManager:210 run       : Function on_device_property_changed on SerialManager failed
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 97, in get
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     prop = self.call_sync(
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject: Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:  (41)
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 207, in run
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     ret = getattr(inst, func)(*args, **kwargs)
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 52, in on_device_property_changed
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     self.terminate_all_scripts(device["Address"])
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 139, in __getitem__
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     return self.get(key)
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/Base.py", line 110, in get
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]:     raise parse_dbus_error(e)
Oct 25 09:59:19 vrumm /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3114]: blueman.bluez.errors.BluezDBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject Method "Get" with signature "ss" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" doesn't exist
```

I've also tried resetting my bluetooth device and of course rebooting, but to no avail.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.